# Using JavaScript/JSON in your Ebay listings to post user selected options back to you

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am seeing some Ebay users create listings where data is dynamically sent to and fetched back from external sources. This can be a shipping calculator or some variants you have provided for a product in a drop-down list.

[See example here](http://cgi.ebay.com.au/New-Intel-i7-930-Quad-Core-Gaming-Desktop-Computer-PC-/220572351614)

Somehow data is sent to a PHP page which returns the postcode as an image

Also the upgrade drop down lists seem to send JSON objects back to a PHP page etc.

What is exactly involved in this solution and if there's a good guide/script resource for Ebay listings out there that will let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See what I did -> opened the link you posted, opened the listing description with FireBug, found the JS script withing the listing description, which is not a complicated one.
So I guess you only need to look at the script to learn what they did there.
I would guess it uses JSONP or similar techique. You can also use IFRAME b.t.w

Comment: Yeah I had a look at the script, but obviously can't look at what's on their server. Do you think all that upgrade list actually submits to the seller when the user presses the buy it now button? Or does it constantly send them data even when users are just playing around with the drop down list ?

Comment: You can hook in to the page event if you use the Ebay API. I never played with though. I do believe that with smart JS you can track everything that happens on the page, just not sure what will be the overhead of this.

Comment: Dang, so you can hook into the ebay API from javascript code located in the body of the listing... I wonder if there's a tutorial for this if not which Ebay SDK/API manual should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not allowed in item description.
The only option to do it will be using a Flash object that will communicate with a PHP/ASP page on your server (this is allowed).